# How do I loop through dictionaries values having different datatypes using .title()?

Tags: python

I want to loop through a dictionary which has values in both string and integers. Here is I have done so far:

```
person={'fname':'harry','lname':'max','age':22,'city':'ktm'}
    for value in person.values():
        print(str(value.title()))
```

My desired output is :

`Harry
Max
22
Ktm`

The error I am getting is:

> AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'title'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to turn `22` (which is an `int` in the dict) into a string before you can use the `.title()` method

```
person={'fname':'harry','lname':'max','age':22,'city':'ktm'}
for value in person.values():
    print(str(value).title(), end=" ")
```

Output:

```
Harry Max 22 Ktm
```

Answer (score 0):

We can not do `int.title()`, so we should do `str(int).title()`.

Change:

```
print(str(value.title()))
```

To:

```
print(str(value).title())
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because `age` is an integer, and it you cannot call `.title()` function on it. you need to convert it to a string first. try to use the following code instead :

`print(str(value).title())`

Answer (score 0):

You dont even need iteration here in python3

```
person={'fname':'harry','lname':'max','age':22,'city':'ktm'}
print(f"{person['fname']} {person['lname']} {person['age']} {person['city']}")
```

You can make it a function

```
def print_dict(person):
    print(f"{person['fname']} {person['lname']} {person['age']} {person['city']}")
```

and pass the dict as an argument